# Ionic 3: endpoint request return to a page - how to

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal (in Laravel) to send notifications to my Ionic app. 
When a user sends a message via web to another user, OneSignal pushes a notification to the receiver. This notification should open the  messages screen. Instead, it is opening a browser window with the endpoint return, a JSON.

Here's how I create the push notification (endpoint):

```
\OneSignal::sendNotificationToUser(
 $request->get('mensagem'),
 $notification->notification_id,
 $url = url('api/mensagens/show-messages?remetente='.$remetente.'&destinatario='.$destinatario.'&auth_id='.auth()->user()->id),
 $data = null,
 $buttons = null,
 $schedule = null
);
```

So, when I send the message, I'm receiving notification in my app as expected. When I open the notification, [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lQOM.jpg).

What am I doing wrong? How to call the messages page correctly when I click in the notification?

Comment: Of the notfication not opening inside the app then you did declare a wrong package name in firebase console. And on click on the notfication inside onenotfication open use router.navigate(['message']) and it will navigate to messages, and if you need to pass some params then in your api send id or data with $data and in notfication open tou get the result.data.params or whatever